# Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission - Output to shell?

Tags: powershell, printing, output, host

When i use a Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission command in processing many users to remove permissions from, it does not output to host every line ...it just shows a blank Powershell window until it is done, unless the user to be deleted permissions for does not have rights, then an error is returned.

Is there a way to make Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission output a line for each person it removes?

The code i use for removing is as follows:

```
#This script imports data from "PFPerm.csv" and Removes permissions for all users in the file.
Write-Host "Removing users...White text = OK ADDED!" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "If a user DOES NOT exist there will be *RED TEXT* stating it was not found.." -ForegroundColor Magenta
Write-Host "If a user is being removed, it will not show any feedback to the screen, just wait for processing to complete.." -ForegroundColor Yellow
"`n"
$Users= Import-CSV -Encoding Unicode H:\Temp\PublicFolder-powershell\PFPerm.csv 
#The switch in this line, prevents confirmation popups from requiring user input and supresses them silently [-Confirm:$false]
foreach ($User in $Users){Get-PublicFolder -identity \$($User.Identity) -recurse | Remove-publicfolderclientpermission -Confirm:$false -User $User.User}
```

If I use `$VerbosePreference = "Continue"` and the `-Verbose` parameter, it shows the output i want to caputure and display, but there is too much un-necessary info and I would not want "VERBOSE" to be at the front of the line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done. As the official help suggests, this command has an empty output field.

"If the Output Type field is blank, the cmdlet doesn't return data."
[image: screenshot]
See more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/management/exchange-management-shell-cmdlet-input-and-output-types

Comment: The correct answer to your question has already been given, and it's unlikely to change over time, regardless of whether it's relevant to you or not. You need to look for workaround solutions.